# How to Find links and go to them in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Hi what would be the way to go the url href="#locations/16381/schedules ?
It is the value of the href attribute? right
Of an a element "a" ? right

and if i want to get this href by finding the "a" element with  attribute data-original-title="Schedules"
is it possible ?

i turn around with `document.getElementById()
document.getElementsByTagName()`

etc... i'm completly lost.. (i have to say i'm just learning JS at this time :)

Here the DOM :

````
<div id="filter-region" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><div>
</div></div>
<div id="list-region" class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12"><div><div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><div class="well">
  <div class="media">
    <div class="media-left media-middle">
      <a href="#locations/16381"><img src="https://api.staffomaticapp.com/system/logos/16381/api/Picture1.png?1451550438" width="51" height="51" class="img
-rounded media-object"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
      <h4 class="location-name"><a href="#locations/16381">Vélo</a></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul class="clearfix list-inline location-navigation"><li><a title="" href="#locations/16381" data-original-title="Dashboard">
  <i class="fa fa-tachometer fa-lg fa-fw"></i>
  <span class="text">Dashboard</span>
</a>
</li><li><a title="" href="#locations/16381/schedules" data-original-title="Schedules">
  <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg fa-fw"></i>
  <span class="text">Schedules</span>
</a>
</li><li><a title="" href="#locations/16381/absences" data-original-title="Absences">
  <i class="fa fa-plane fa-lg fa-fw"></i>
  <span class="text">Absences</span>
</a>
```
````

i try almost every document.getElement() i could find lol...
i try to learn jquery same time as people say it easier...
 but everything mixed up in my smokin' head...

My clue is that i have to play with parents and child
before i could find my "a" element... but no clear enough ... that's it ??

Plus if someone got "THE" tutorial or cheat sheet to play with DOM (from client-side point of view) i didn't find one to make me understand well

thanks

edit :
i almost answer my question...  $('TagOfElement').get(NumberOfTheNode) give me  $('a').get(18).click() to go to the url yes jquery made it

but still how could i find it with data-original-title="Schedules" ? and in strict JS ?

it would be a nice thing to put on same post all the different ways to access elements in a dom.

Blessed love

Comment: If you're using jQuery, please [edit] your question and add that tag to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is complicated by the fact that the DOM does not include classes or ids, which would make the search easier. As it is, here is how I solved it (see the Javascript section):

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

var anchor, ref;
for (var element of links) {
  if (element.getAttribute('data-original-title')=='Schedules') {
    anchor = element;
    ref = element.getAttribute('href');
    }
  }

console.log(anchor);
console.log(ref);
```

```html
<div id="filter-region" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><div>
</div></div>
<div id="list-region" class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12"><div><div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><div class="well">
  <div class="media">
    <div class="media-left media-middle">
      <a href="#locations/16381"><img src="https://api.staffomaticapp.com/system/logos/16381/api/Picture1.png?1451550438" width="51" height="51" class="img
-rounded media-object"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
      <h4 class="location-name"><a href="#locations/16381">Vélo</a></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul class="clearfix list-inline location-navigation"><li><a title="" href="#locations/16381" data-original-title="Dashboard">
  <i class="fa fa-tachometer fa-lg fa-fw"></i>
  <span class="text">Dashboard</span>
</a>
</li><li><a title="" href="#locations/16381/schedules" data-original-title="Schedules">
  <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg fa-fw"></i>
  <span class="text">Schedules</span>
</a>
</li><li><a title="" href="#locations/16381/absences" data-original-title="Absences">
  <i class="fa fa-plane fa-lg fa-fw"></i>
  <span class="text">Absences</span>
</a>
```

Comment: First time I see the `element of X` syntax.

Comment: @Ibu https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: great... your code is cristal clear... i will try to reproduce it for my next step ... i will update later

Answer (score 0):

With jquery in case you have multiple elements with same class:

```
$( "a" ).each(function( index ) {
   if ($(this).data('original-title') =='Schedules' ){
    var url = $(this).attr('href')
    // do something
   }
});
```

or :

```
var url2 = $("a[data-original-title=Schedules]").attr('href');
```

plain javascript :

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var dataoriginal = elements[i].getAttribute('data-original-title');
        if(dataoriginal == 'Schedules'){
            var url3 = elements[i].getAttribute("href");
       //do something
    }
}
```